# Finding out if an Expression contains a "lonely" ParameterExpression

Tags: c#, expression

Is there a simple way of finding out if an Expression contains a ParameterExpression that isn't further wrapped in for example a MemberExpression.

Example:

`x => x.Method() ? x : null` <= 1 occurence of x without any further evaluation

`x => x.Method() ? x.Property : null` <= 0 occurences of x without any further evaluation

Simply put my use case is that I know the Method (no params) and Property values and want to find out if this is enough to evaluate the expression without fetching the entire "object" from store.

Edit:
My example is maybe to simplified. There are more Expression types that needs to be handled (for example UnaryExpression).

`x => ((Cast) x).Property` <= 0 occurences of x without any further evaluation

I'm looking for an answer to the following question:

given an expression, if I know all method return values and property values of the input parameter but not the parameter value itself, can I evaluate the expression?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: It's .net 3.5 (but I also have a .net 4 version where I could use this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on .NET 4 or later, you can use [`ExpressionVisitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) for this.

I'm not quite sure how you define "lonely parameter", but if you want to exclude *direct* method calls, member accesses and indexer accesses on parameters, you can use something like this (untested):

Use it like this:

```
new MyExpressionVisitor().GetNumLonelyParameterExpressions(myExpression.Body)
```

---

```
public class MyExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private int numLonelyParameterExpressions;

    public int GetNumLonelyParameterExpressions(Expression expression)
    {
        numLonelyParameterExpressions = 0;
        Visit(expression);
        return numLonelyParameterExpressions;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        // Every time we encounter a lonely parameter, increment.
        numLonelyParameterExpressions++;
        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        // Don't visit parameters that have methods called on them.
         var expr = (node.Object is ParameterExpression)
            ? Expression.Default(node.Object.Type)
            : node.Object;

        // We need to make sure the arguments are visited though.
        return base.VisitMethodCall(node.Update(expr, node.Arguments));
    }


    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
          // Don't visit parameters with member accesses on them.
          if (node.Expression is ParameterExpression)
              return Expression.Default(node.Type);

          return base.VisitMember(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitIndex(IndexExpression node)
    {
         // Same idea here.
         var expr = (node.Object is ParameterExpression)
             ? Expression.Default(node.Object.Type)
             : node.Object;

         return base.VisitIndex(node.Update(expr, node.Arguments));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my current approach (I have my own ExpressionVisitor for 3.5). However there are more Expressions that needs to be counted and I'm afraid I missing some. One is for example UnaryExpression: x => ((Cast) x).Property.

Comment: @lindstromhenrik: I guess you're going to have to define 'lonely' really well as if you include that, it's pretty vague.

Comment: I've tried to give a better explaination but I'm still not really sure what to call the problem ;-)